# Why do I get empty brackets as a response to a http GET request

Tags: java, database, rest, api, request

I have a Maven Project in Java. I can successfully bring out data from my database in my testclass. However, when I do a GET request from Postman to webb Service it simply wont give me a response with the array in JSON format. It only returns an empty []. I have been at this now for more than 30 hours and can't fix it.

I have tried converting it to JSON before hand using GSON. I have tried the methods I use to bring out the data from a main class, and it works succsessfully. It just doesn't work when I do it through the http request.

//method that works to bring out the data from DB into array

```
public List<ResultLadok> getLadokResultsArrayList(){
    //----------Test få ut DB i ArrayList-------------------        
    try{
        //1. get a connection to database
        Connection conn = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ladoksimulation", "root", "admin");

        //2. create a statement
        Statement myStmt = conn.createStatement();
        //3. Execute SQL query
        ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from resultat");
        //4. process the result set
        //för in resultat set in i lista genom while-statement
        while(myRs.next()){
            addResult(myRs.getString("betyg"), myRs.getInt("poäng"), myRs.getInt("provNr"),
                     myRs.getString("termin"), myRs.getString("date"), myRs.getString("kurskod"),
                     myRs.getString("kurstillfälle"));

        }        
    }        
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }    
    //returnera listan 
    return resultList;
}
```

//method to add results into arrayList

```
public void addResult (String betyg, int poäng, int provNr, String termin, 
        String datum, String kurskod, String kurstillfälle) {

    ResultLadok resLadok = new ResultLadok();

    resLadok.setBetyg(betyg);
    resLadok.setPoäng(poäng);
    resLadok.setProvNr(provNr);
    resLadok.setTermin(termin);
    resLadok.setDate(datum);
    resLadok.setKurskod(kurskod);
    resLadok.setKurstillfälle(kurstillfälle);


    resultList.add(resLadok);        
}
```

//the web service getting request from postman

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getJson() {

    DriverDBLadok_testing p = new DriverDBLadok_testing();
    List<ResultLadok> resultList = p.getLadokResultsArrayList();


    return Response.ok(resultList)
            .build();
}
```

I expect to get out a list of the data in the DB in JSON format. Instead i get this: []

Many thanks!

Comment: its seems like you `resultList ` is empty

Comment: Is `resultList` the same object instance in `getLadokResultsArrayList`  and `addResult` ?

Comment: Try printing or debugging the value of reultList in getJson() method before returning the response. Secondly try using Response.ok().entity(resultList).build();

Comment: Ive tried that now and it still returns empty brackets.

When I call the getLadokResultsArrayList() method from the same package it works ((but another class and .java file). It also works to print it out in console from the same package..

But when I go into the web application and call the method it doesn't work. Hence is the problem how I declare the instance variable? It is now declared public ( public  List<ResultLadok> resultList  = new ArrayList();).

I guess the problem is then: why can't I call the application project from my webb application?